# Как с помощью Cython вызвать функцию c callback, написанную на C?

Tags: python, c, cython

Есть функция на C:

```
//my_f.h
typedef void (*callback_t)(int result);

void my_f(int a, int b, int c, callback_t cb);


//my_f.c
#include "my_f.h"

void my_f(int a, int b, int c, callback_t cb)
{
    cb(a * b + c);
}
```

собираем в библиотеку коммандой:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmy_f.so my_f.c
```

Теперь нужно из собранной библиотеки libmy_f.so правильно вызвать функцию `my_f()` в Python.
Вопрос следущий -- как эту библиотеку правильно обернуть используя Cython?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [boost](http://www.boost.org), который позаботится о конвертировании типов и прочих жизненных радостях:

Плюсовый код:

```
std::string bar(const std::string& s)
{
    return s + "!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("bar", bar);
}
```

Питоновый код:

```
import foo

print (foo.bar('what?'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы только одну функцию вызвать, [удобно `ctypes` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes):

```
#file: run_my_f_ctypes.py
import ctypes

@ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int)
def callback(result):
    print(result)

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libmy_f.so')
lib.my_f(1, 2, 3, callback)
# -> 5
```

Если нужно именно Cython использовать, то чтобы можно было бы передать обычную Питон-функцию, обратный вызов должен принимать `void*` аргумент -- [пример](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#callbacks).

Если вы не можете интерфейс `my_f` библиотеки изменить, чтобы `callback_t` принимал бы `void*` параметр (через который можно Питон-функцию передать как показано в [примере](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#callbacks)), то в качестве обходного решения (hack), можно через глобальную переменную функцию передать:

```
#file: cy_my_f.pyx
cdef extern from "my_f.h":
    ctypedef void (*callback_t)(int result)
    void my_f(int a, int b, int c, callback_t cb)

def call_with_callback(a, b, c, callback):
    global py_callback
    py_callback = callback
    my_f(a, b, c, c_callback)

cdef void c_callback(int result):
    py_callback(result)
```

В этом случае только один вызов может быть активен одновременно.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#file: run_my_f.py
import pyximport  # $ pip install cython
pyximport.install()  # compile on-the-fly
import cy_my_f

cy_my_f.call_with_callback(1, 2, 3, print)
# -> 5
```

Обратите внимание Питон-функция `print` передана как есть.

Чтобы собрать `cy_my_f` Питон-модуль из `cy_my_f.pyx`, необходимо указать путь к `my_f` библиотеке:

```
#file: cy_my_f.pyxbld
import os
from distutils.extension import Extension

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
             libraries=["my_f"],
             include_dirs=[dirname], # where my_f.h
             library_dirs=[dirname], # where -lmy_fy
    )

def make_setup_args():
    return dict(script_args=["--verbose"])
```

Во время `import cy_my_f`, `pyximport` (часть cython) автоматически использует `cy_my_f.pyxbld`, чтобы собрать `cy_my_f` модуль расширения для CPython, определённый в `cy_my_f.pyx` файле.